# How to put ElasticSearch mappings using the new java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to define a particular field as being of type keyword, using the latest java API Elasticsearch class. But I can't figure out how to do it and can't find examples of it either.

I expected to be able to write something like this:

```
ElasticsearchClient client = ....

client.putMappings(m -> m.etc...)
```

but I can't find any method in the ElasticsearchClient that looks like it would allow me to put some mappings.

This is something that I find very frustrating with the new java API. It's very fluent, but not very well documented. Most of the ES documentation and examples I find out there describe things in terms of raw JSON objects. But I often can't find documentation and examples that show how to build these JSON object using the newest java API.

Answer (score 0):

Today I was facing the same problem and retorted to looking at the test code in the [repository for the Java client](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/), which might contain an [example test](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/blob/main/java-client/src/test/java/co/elastic/clients/elasticsearch/end_to_end/RequestTest.java#L382) of what you are looking for:

```
client = ElasticsearchTestServer.global().client();

String index = "testindex";
Map<String, Property> fields = Collections.singletonMap("keyword", Property.of(p -> p.keyword(k -> k.ignoreAbove(256))));
Property text = Property.of(p -> p.text(t -> t.fields(fields)));
    
client.indices().create(c -> c
    .index(index)
    .mappings(m -> m
        .properties("id", text)
        .properties("name", p -> p
            .object(o -> o
                .properties("first", text)
                .properties("last", text)
            )
        )
    )
);
```

The challenge for me was that the MappingRequest does not accept anything other than a generic property instead of a typed property directly, like DateProperty.